# Multiple (custom) Sendgrid / Twilio templates, based on different third-party clients

Tags: twilio, sendgrid

We have the situation where we send a Twilio Verify SMS or email to an end-user, but this can be on behalf of various clients. We have **one** Twilio account servicing them all.

One client wants a custom response showcasing their logo. Is this possible given the constraint outlined above? I know customization is possible in principle, but how would the template selected be based off the request we send to Twilio?

Twilio docs do not explicitly address this point.